# Ingresar fracciones textbox C#

Tags: c#, double

Tengo que hacer un programa que resuelva la determinante de una matriz, `n11 = double.Parse(b11.Text);`y funciona bien con enteros. Pero también quiero que funcione si ingreso números como 1/4, 3/16 y así.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que lea la fracción para realizar la operación?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Oscar Rojas, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla! También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Si tratas de que se calcule cualquier tipo de operación introducida, es un tema bastante complejo. Si siempre se va a tratar de fracciones, es muy sencillo. Simplemente debes analizar el texto introducido buscando si tiene un `/`, y en ese caso hacer un `Split` por ese caracter y dividir ambas partes. Trata de hacerlo como te digo y si tienes algun problema pulsa en [edit], añade el código y te ayudamos a resolverlo.

Comment: mira este enlace, con la clase Math lo puedes hacer muy sencillo utilizando casi cualquier operación, no solo la división: http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Comment: Tienes una clase para operaciones sencillas en [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23061/MathParser-Math-Formula-Parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que usar String.Split

```
string[] aux;
double resultado;
if (textBox1.Text.Contains("/"))
{
    aux = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' }, 2);
    resultado = double.Parse(aux[0]) / double.Parse(aux[1]);
}
else
{
    resultado = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}

MessageBox.Show(resultado.ToString());
```

**EDIT:** En el caso de que necesites que se pueda ingresar fracciones más complejas como 3/4/6 podes hacer lo siguiente..

```
string[] aux;
double resultado=0;

if (textBox1.Text.Contains("/"))
{
      aux = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' }, textBox1.Text.Length-1);
      resultado = double.Parse(aux[0]);
      foreach(string numero in aux.Skip(1))
      {
      resultado /= double.Parse(numero);                    
      }
}
else
{
        resultado = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}



MessageBox.Show(resultado.ToString());
```

Es posible que exista una manera más simple de resolverlo, pero es lo primero que se me ocurrió, saludos!